# How can I bind my mouse wheel to scroll down with a key, and this key is.. (AHK)

Tags: autohotkey

So, basically, I play this game and want to be able to bind any key to my mouse wheel scrolling down, where a light tap would only scroll slightly (This is for a game, where it's precise. Like.. reeling in a little vs a lot.)

Anyway, I want the key to still be triggered even if other keys are being pressed, since I usually have to hold several keys in the game and reel (use the mouse wheel scroll down to reel) while holding these keys for advance maneuvers..

Any idea how to do that in AHK?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Lets assume the key is `x`

If you want the key press to send only 1 scrolldown when it's held down:

```
*x::SendInput {wheeldown}
```

If you want the keypress to keep sending scrolldown as long as it's held:

```
*x::
While GetKeyState("x", "p")
{
    SendInput, {WheelDown}
    ;Sleep, 250 ; Add a delay if you want to increase the interval between keystokes.
}
return
```

And btw, you might want to make this a context sensitive hotkey( a hotkey that it activated only when the game is running.) or it will become a PITA.

You can find some info about it [here](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context)

Comment: I need that key ~x~ to work even when I am using it in a combo.. and the game is UNity. Say I press (W and Shift) to blast forward in the game (Shift is gas, W is forward) and want to reel in my hooks on a target, if I press WShiftX, will that work?

Comment: How can I make it specific to the Unity Plugin playing at that moment?

Comment: I just edited it. adding the `*` modifier will allow the hotkeys to work even if other keys are held down.

Comment: Time to test it give me a moment ;D

Comment: You can make it context specific with `#ifWinactive`. There are some examples in the [documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm#Context)

Comment: You need to find out the title of the window. Autohotkey does provide a window info tool. It'll `%ProgramFiles%\Autohtokey\AU3_Spy.exe` by default. Find out the title of the window, and add `#IfWinactive, {The title of the window}` before the `*x::`

Comment: Um, how could I do that with the z key?

Comment: Um. Just use `z` instead of `x`. You really do need to check the [documentation](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm).

Comment: It's not working with LAlt, and when in the game it's not working if I'm clicked in it.

Comment: You'll have to change `GetKeyState("x", "p")` to `GetKeyState("LAlt", "p")`